# xsl-fo how to put the line / square around a character

Tags: xsl-fo

the `<fo:inline text-decoration="underline">` can put a line under a text. but is there something to put the lines around a character? I would like to put a character inside of the solid bordered square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border="..."` and alike is your friend, works very similar to html.

You can specify it like `border="1px solid black"` or you can specify width, color, style etc. separate for top, bottom, etc. Note that it does not put a box around every character but around that entity (i.e. e.g. `fo:inline`) where you specify it.

See [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#common-border-padding-and-background-properties)  for details.

Comment: There's also sample FO and PDF files for "Character style setting (font-style、border-style etc.)" at https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/

Comment: Thank you so much Stefan. This works perfect for me! :)

Comment: @xslnewMember, the way to say Thankyou is to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark. You're welcome!